# The JSP specification requires that an attribute name is preceded by whitespace

Tags: xml, jsp

white space in comments crash the website

```
<!--<s:form name="exportNews"id="exportNewsForm" theme="simple"  namespace="/"  action="exportNews" onsubmit="return validate(this);"  method="post"> 
        <s:submit value="Export"  />
         </s:form> -->
```

the code that crash my website is a comment. after i add a space before id=...
the bug fixed.

can someone tell me the reason?

Comment: The *XML* specification requires that an attribute name is preceded by white space.

Comment: @EJP why xml specification?? even if i wrap the node with <!---->, it's still a node?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't really commented anything out there. That code will generate an HTML comment in the output whose content is given by processing the JSP tags. If you want to actually comment out broken code in a JSP you should use `<%-- JSP comment tags --%>`, whose content is completely ignored by the JSP parser and won't generate any output.

The error message is correct, you need to add a space between the closing quote of the `name` attribute and the beginning of the `id`, but if you commented it out using `<%--` instead of `<!--` then you wouldn't get an error.